# Writing large varchar(MAX) to file using t-sql stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, file-io

I am trying to run the following commands to generate a file and populate the file with `varchar(MAX)` amount of data.  Here is the issue, when I try to run the code it creates the files but they are empty.  I know the `@classString` variable has data in it.  Is there a string enclosing sequence I can wrap around the `@classString` to delimit it?  I am trying to generate a script so I am assuming the @classString contains characters that are interfering with the file write.

```
SET @sqlString = 'echo off > ' + @FilePath + '\' + @table_name + '.cs"'
exec xp_cmdshell @sqlString
SET @sqlString = 'echo ' + @classString + ' >> ' + @FilePath + '\' + @table_name + '.cs"'
exec xp_cmdshell @sqlString
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, but have you considered a small external script that queries the database for the necessary data and writes the files? Writing files using `xp_cmdshell` is extremely awkward and often leads to permissions problems.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to delimit or quote the whole string, instead you need to escape any shell metacharacters within it using the ^ symbol. For example:

```
SET @classString = (SELECT REPLACE(@classString, '>', '^>'))
SET @classString = (SELECT REPLACE(@classString, '&', '^&'))
```

...and so on for any cmdshell metacharacters that may feature in your string.

Comment: I tried and the files are still empty.  In a nutshell, the proc generates entities(poco) based on db table structure.  If I print the output and paste to a query window, it encounters a problem with the first using statement, not to mention all of the special characters of c#.  I would need to either escape everything or I need a different way to write the text to a file.

Comment: I think the problem has to do with writing a multi-line varchar to a file.  A single line works but multi-line seems to be a problem.  Is there a way to write multiple lines to a file at one time using xp_cmdshell?